# Using google play services before publishing to Google Play with real accounts

Tags: android, google-play-services

I use Google Play Games Services (I'm using Turn-Based Multiplayer). The game is on Android and other platforms. I need to use test accounts to test Google play services before publishing to Google Play (as described here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub). But what if the app is not Android app? And can I use google play services on Android before publishing with real accounts?

Comment: If the application is not Android application, how would you use Google Play Services which are only for Android?

Comment: why dont you publish a alpha or beta apk of your application and distribute in within some of your test accounts?

Comment: @AmrutBidri I should not publish apk on Google Play. Also the apk will be used by many people with real google+ accounts.

Comment: @StenSoft why only for Android? https://developers.google.com/games/services/ there are more platforms

Comment: @George Oh, I didn't noticed you want Google Play **Games** Services, all other Google Play Services APIs are Android-only. You don't need to upload your application to Google Play, just enter the package name (or bundle ID for iOS) you are using for your game, generate Client ID, set it in the application and add tester accounts.

Comment: @StenSoft I'm newbie in Google Play Services, I didn't mention that I told about **Games** Services, sorry. And how to use not-tester accounts in iOS app? And in Android app without publishing?

Comment: @George That is not possible, your game needs to be published to be accessible for non-tester accounts. You can however try setting some filters that won't allow the game to be installable on any device via Google Play.